# how to make the whole page in the center?

Tags: html, css

The page is here:
https://gentle-day-3026.herokuapp.com/

The css file like this:

https://gentle-day-3026.herokuapp.com/stylesheets/base.css 
another is  to use reset.css to replace the base.css
(the new user just 2 hyperlink allowed)

Try to change some many times, include methods like:

```
<body> 
 <div id="divMain"> 
  ... 
 </div> 
</body> 


body 
{ 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
 text-align: center; 
} 
#divMain
{ 
 margin: 0 auto; 
 padding: 0; 
 width: 1024px; 
 text-align: left; 
}
```

but it didn't work.
Thank you for your help!

I even test it in a very simple html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/base.css" media="Screen" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="divMain">
     <h1> hello </h1>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

It still did not work!

Comment: Your posted code should work if you want to horizontal-center-align `#divMain`. If it does not works, there should be something somewhere (maybe in `reset.css`) disturbing it.

Comment: Remove the `width` from the `body`. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is fine. But you given a width to the `body`. Remove the `width` attribute from there. Try this CSS and it works:

```
body {
    color: #999999;
    font: 14px/1.5em "Lucida Grande",Arial,sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
    width: auto;
}
```

[image]

See `base.css` line no. 8 has the same `width: 720px;` for the body! And also, for the `<div align="center">` change it to `<div class="center">` and give css as `.center {width: 720px; margin: auto;}`. Please try this and let us know.

Finally you should be having this:

```
.center {width: 720px; margin: auto;}

<div class="center">
```

Comment: It was working from my chrome. Let me post a screenshot! Please make the suggested edits. You had given width in wrong place and margin auto needs to be given there.

Comment: I modified the base.css to disable the width and saved, but in firebug, the width values is still existing, disable it in firebug, the whole page is on the center. In fact, I cancel the body's width setting in the base.css file.Reload the page, the problem is still existing: not center.

Comment: You have saved right, lemme check from my side and will let you know what you need to change. See `base.css` line no. 8 has the same `width: 720px;` for the body! And also, for the `<div align="center">` change it to `<div class="center">` and give css as `.center {width: 720px; margin: auto;}`. Please try this and let us know.

Comment: Really appreciated your nice help!

Answer (score 4):

On your current page, `body` has a fixed width of `720px`. Remove this. Next, set the fixed width on your outer-most `div` that sits just inside the `body`. Additionally, give this `div` a margin of `0 auto`, which will result in it being centered horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your body width to 100%, your `<div>` to whatever size you want (eg 720px) and its margin to 0 auto.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code that you have posted works perfectly for aligning #divMain to the center (horizontally)...

Looking at the code you have posted for your site, it looks like you have defined a fixed width for your `body` element (see line 12 of `base.css`). Removing this fixed width, and then moving the correct width to the wrapper `div` (currently set using `align="center"`) should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.divMain{
  width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

May be it helps you.
Try to add this style in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here:

1. **You set the margin of <body> to be 0 (inline css above).** What's more, <body>'s width is only 720px (base.css, line 8), which is smaller than the width of most desktop viewports. As a result, <body> snaps to the left of the viewport, with margin-left as 0 and plenty of space to the right. With <body> aligned to the left, its children (such as #divMain) cannot possibly look centered. What you can do is to either center <body> by using `margin: 20px auto`, or by setting <body>'s width to be 100% to fill the entire viewport.
2. **The width of the child, #divMain, is larger than that of its body.** You will have to set the width of #divMain to be smaller than 720px (e.g. 500px) - the only way for a child to be centered horizontally within its parent using `margin:0 auto` is for the parent's width to be larger. Of course, I don't think you intended to have #divMain smaller than 1024px in width, so I'd suggest setting <body>'s width to be 100%, which almost guarantees that its width will be larger than #divMain's.

In short, you can either have:

`body{width:720px;margin:20px auto;} #divMain{width:500px;margin:0 auto;}`

or

`body{width:100%;} #divMain{width:1024px;margin:0 auto;}`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="div-body-width">
....
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

/*Insert here your width*/

.div-body-width {
    width: 1024px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the content of your body in a div :

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
      ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Then in your css :

```
#page {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I check the source code on his website and I didn't saw it... Maybe I'm tired :p